# Delete linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hey I wonder about
I have written a C++ linked list, where I call a destructor to go through an allocated linked list and delete every node found. However what I found is that although it goes through the linked list and delete every occurance it will still print out values. Although just some scrap values.

But shouldn't it be when I delete the linked_list it shouldn't be printable next time?
I'm create a linked list by using the `new`, and `delete` when I remove the list

```
sorted_list::~sorted_list()
{
    // Destructor implementation
    destroy(this->first);
    cout << "Destructor called sorted_list" << endl;
}

void sorted_list::destroy(list_link* item)
{
  if (item)
  {
    destroy(item->next);
    delete item;
  }
}
```

### print function

```
void sorted_list::print() {

    if(this->first)
    {
        iteratorn *traverse = new iteratorn(this->first);
        while( !traverse->iterator_end() )
        {
            cout << traverse->iterator_get_key() << " ";
            traverse->iterator_next();
        }
        delete traverse;
    }
    else
        cout << "list empty" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Not enough code. Show the code that builds the list, and show the code that prints out values that it shouldn't.

Comment: You delete this->first twice (once in destroy).

Comment: You don't need to assign `NULL` (or even 0) to `this->first` in the destructor. The list is released, it's gone, utterly inaccessible.

Comment: @Roger Pate @wilhelmtell thanks for input I remove the double delete of this->first now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you access a destructed object, the behaviour is undefined. In fact, deleting an object doesn't clear the memory, just marks it available, so if you execute some operations on already deleted object, they may do something reasonable. But again, the object is destructed, so you must not access it.

Of course, you should not retain any pointers to the object belonging to the linked list after it's destructed, because those objects will be destructed as well.

By the way, your `sorted_list::destroy` is recursive, which is quite inefficient. You would need perhaps to replace it with iterative approach:

```
void sorted_list::destroy(list_link* item)
{
    while (item)
    {
        list_link* old = item;
        item = item->next;
        delete old;
    }
}
```

(And you should take into account @Roger Pate's comment and not delete `this->first` the second time after calling `destroy(this->first);`.)

Comment: Yeah, always destroy lists iteratively, because the recursive method might run out of stack space if the list is too large.

Comment: @Vlad @Timo this is not accurate. Any modern C++ compiler should know how to optimize away at least tail-recursions. Here it is actually straight-forward to convert the recursion to a tail-recursion, and the result object-code should be identical to that of a loop: `if( ! item ) return; list_link* next = item->next; delete item; destroy(next);`

Comment: @wilhelmtell: it's a dangerous practise to assume that the optimizer will optimize the recursion out for you. Unless such an optimization is guaranteed by C++ standard, I would not rely on it.

Comment: I've been trying around, and still can't get why I still retain scrap values. I actually want the program to crash when I try to access an already deleted linked list, but instead it will print out some scrap values. I have added in my print function also.

Comment: @starcom: you cannot get a guaranteed crash, the behaviour is just undefined. Look, when you destruct the object, the memory gets freed, and returned to the global memory pool. So it may be overwritten with any values at any time, or it may as well still have its old values, you never know. If it happens to have the old values, your print function may not crash. And you cannot guarantee that the function will crash, because this needs the memory to be filled with some special values--but that is not possible, because the memory can be reused by other objects. You see?

Comment: @starcom: actually there is a way to get a _guaranteed_ crash if accessing the freed memory under linux (for your debug builds). Look at [efence](http://linux.die.net/man/3/efence). It replaces the standard allocation/deallocation functions in such a way that the program crashes at any access to the freed memory. Indeed vert useful for debugging. There must be something of that kind under Windows as well. (All this is useful only for debugging, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

When declaring the link, which probably looks more or less like this:

```
struct list_link {
    int data;
    list_link *next;
};
```

You could slip a **destructor** in:

```
struct list_link {
    int data;
    list_link *next;
    ~list_link() { delete next; }  // MAKE SURE NULL-TERMINATED LIST
};
```

This way if you want to delete the list you can simply:

```
delete first;
```

MAGIC!!

Answer (score 0):

Missing part is nullifying. After deleting, you must nullify the first node at least. I would nullify every node after delete.