# Empty a linked-list object

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have my linked list code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    Node *next;
    Node(string name, int age)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
        this->next = nullptr;
    }
};

class List
{
private:
    Node *head;
    int size;

public:
    List()
    {
        this->head = nullptr;
        this->size = 0;
    }

    void insert(string name, int age)
    {
        Node *nodenew = new Node(name, age);
        nodenew->next = nullptr;
        if (this->head == nullptr)
        {
            this->head = nodenew;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *auxi = this->head;
            while (auxi->next != nullptr)
            {
                auxi = auxi->next;
            }
            auxi->next = nodenew;
        }
        this->size = this->size + 1;
    }

    void print()
    {
        if (this->head == nullptr)
        {
            cout << "List is empty"<<endl;
        }

        Node *auxi = this->head;
        cout<<to_string(this->size)+" users in the linked list"<<endl;

        while (auxi != nullptr)
        {

            cout << auxi->name << ", " << auxi->age << endl;
            auxi = auxi->next;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    List linkedList;
    
    linkedList.insert("David", 56);
    linkedList.insert("Susan", 25);
    linkedList.insert("Kim", 41);
    linkedList.insert("Charles", 23);
    linkedList.insert("Bob", 20);
    linkedList.insert("James", 75);
    linkedList.insert("Carl", 36);
    linkedList.insert("Andy", 78);
    linkedList.print();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I did `insert` method, `print` method. And now want I want is to delete all nodes in the `linkedList` object, so I would like to know if there is some way to make for example something like `linkedList = nullptr` or something similar to delete all data in my linked list.

I tried to make that in the main method:

```
linkedList = nullptr;
```

But my compiler shows me this error:

```
no operator "=" matches these operands
```

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: There is nothing like that. You will have to write a method that will every previously allocated node yourself.

Comment: I see you haven't learned about constructors yet.  Try this: `Node(string name_, int age_) : name{move(name_)}, age{age_}, next{nullptr} { }`

Comment: @Eljay You are right, I tried to add `beginner` tag but It is not available

Comment: Do the same sort of looping you do in `print`, but instead of printing the node, `delete` it. Take care to make sure you have advanced the tracking pointer (`auxi = auxi->next;`) before deleting it. Typically you'll need to have a temporary copy of the pointer so you can delete the copy after you've moved past it.

Comment: @trincot I read before and I found that it is not the best to use free to deallocate a node

Comment: True, you should use `delete` when having allocated with `new`. See [Delete linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112905/delete-linked-list). Point is, there are so many Q&A on this, this is certainly a duplicate question.

Comment: @narocac There's no "the best idea". Memory allocated with `malloc()` must be released with `free()`, memory allocated with `new` must be released with `delete` and memory allocated with `new[]` must be released with `delete[]`. Mixing them will likely crash your program. But the general idea is the same, you only have to replace `free(node);` with `delete node;`.

Comment: [Here is a really good presentation from Herb Sutter on using Smart Pointers to totally avoid `new`/`delete`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE). He spends some time on linked lists. In general I'm not a big fan of smart pointers in linked lists, they limit the size of the list to how deep you can recurse the node destruction before overflowing the stack, but if the size of the list is already limited, take advantage.

Answer (score 1):

`linkedList = nullptr;` won't work, since it makes no sense. `linkedList` isn't a pointer. It has a pointer inside of it, but it's not itself a pointer. Besides, if that did work, it wouldn't delete the nodes, so it would be a memory leak.

You should create a function `empty()` (or more usually called `clear()`) in your `List` class. Make it so it deletes all the nodes, then sets `head` to `nullptr` and `size` to `0`. Then in `main()`, you can call `linkedList.empty();` (or `linkedList.clear();`)

Comment: @RemyLebeau what was the point of the edit?

Comment: just fixing some grammar, and syntax-highlighting some code elements you missed to highlight (you highlighted some but not all).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I do not code-highlight every single thing that could be code-highlighted, because excessive highlighting is distracting to read.

Comment: Good for you. I prefer to be more consistent. If some identifiers/snippets are code-highlighted, then all identifiers/snippets should be code-highlighted. Makes it easy to see which text is referring to code and which text is not.